# Cactus turning yellow from the base

Tags: succulents, cactus

I was changing the pot that I noticed the part that was in dirt has changed colors, it is not wet or soft just different color[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is called "Cactus corking"; [Read Sublime Succulents article](https://www.sublimesucculents.com/what-is-cactus-corking/) here.

The corking process is different from pathogen-induced or sunburn-induced corking look-alikes. Typically, disease or sunburn may cause irregular patches, scattered somewhat randomly. There are comparative pictures as well. Normally, older plants develop corking on the underside. The outer skin turns harder and aids in supporting the structure as it grows. Although unsightly, the plant may still be propagated from cuttings. It is not necessary, but if you cut the top you can root it, or root any new stems which pop-out in response. They will be normal and will age in the same way.

Since you already uprooted the plant, it is worth examining the base and the roots before repotting: If you feel anything too soft, there may be a root or base rot (for other reasons) but you can cut-off the top and root it.